# NuGet: Restoring packages for... An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I keep getting the following response when trying to install EF 6.4.4 (or any other!!) NuGet package to a project:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.4
Install-Package : The WriteObject and WriteError methods cannot be called from outside the overrides of the BeginProcessing, ProcessRecord, and EndProcessing 
methods, and they can only be called from within the same thread. Validate that the cmdlet makes these calls correctly, or contact Microsoft Customer Support 
Services.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.4
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Alexander, any update about your issue? Please check my answer and let us know if it helps or not.

Comment: @Perry I already did, except for deleting nuget.config. That is, I have had checked all you've suggested before you posted your answer - alas, nothing worked. Anyway, I removed all references and recreated them, now it works.

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for your feedback and since you have your own workaround, I suggest you could add your own answer and then mark it. It will help other community members search and handle similar issues:)

Comment: @Perry Not a solution I'd recommend.In fact this is newly created project, and so the problem is avoided not solved.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. If your project uses `packages.config` nuget package management format, you could run `update-package -reinstall` under `package manager console` to test it. Anyway, you have avoided the issue by some means.

Answer (score 2):

> NuGet: Restoring packages for… An item with the same key has already
> been added

Please try these:

**Suggestion**

**1)** [clean all nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or delete any nuget caches under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\.nuget\packages`

**2)** make sure that you can access the Internet and turn off any firewall or any antivirus software

**Also**, you can try to check if you can access the package under **Manage Nuget packages** by right-click on your project

**3)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under Solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder, then delete `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` and then restart your project to test again.

**Also**, please enable `nuget.org` package source and disable the others under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Sources**

[image]

- Enable `nuget.org` and disable others.
- Run `update-package -reinstall` under **Package Manager Console**
- **Last**, choose the nuget.org as package source and the right target project and then install `EntityFramework` to test again.

[image]

**In addition**, please try to create a new project and then install that package in it to check if the issue occurs only on your current project.